# How to use multiple TEXT funtions in QUERY's second argument?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

Using the the `Query` function with `text()` or `To_text()` function in the second argument works completely fine for me, as in this example:

```
=QUERY({June2019!$M$3:$Z;July2019!$M$3:$Z;August2019!$M$3:$Z},"select 
 SUM(Col5) where Col1 > "&text((Column()-2)*5,"#")&" and Col1 <= 
 "&text((Column()-1)*5,"#")&" label SUM(Col5) ''")
```

However as soon as I use this query function in a more complex way, I get one of two errors:

```
=IF((ISBLANK(B27:27)=False), 
 (QUERY({June2019!$M$3:$Z;July2019!$M$3:$Z;August2019!$M$3:$Z},"select 
 SUM(Col5) where (Col1 > "&text((Column()-2)*5,"#")&") and (Col1 <= 
 "&text((Column()-1)*5,"#")&") label SUM(Col5) 
 ''"))/(QUERY({June2019!$M$3:$Z;July2019!$M$3:$Z;August2019!$M$3:$Z},"select 
 COUNT(Col5) where (Col1 > "&text((Column()-2)*5,"#")&") and (Col1 <= 
 "&text((Column()-1)*5,"#")&") label COUNT(Col5) ''")),)
```

> Error: 
>   Query completed with an empty output.

---

> Error:
>   Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "Col1 "" at line 1, column 24. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B27:27)=FALSE, 
 QUERY({June2019!$M$3:$Z; July2019!$M$3:$Z; August2019!$M$3:$Z}, 
 "select SUM(Col5) 
  where Col1 >  "&(COLUMN()-2)*5&" 
    and Col1 <= "&(COLUMN()-1)*5&"
  label SUM(Col5)''")/
 QUERY({June2019!$M$3:$Z; July2019!$M$3:$Z; August2019!$M$3:$Z},
 "select COUNT(Col5) 
  where Col1 >  "&(COLUMN()-2)*5&"
    and Col1 <= "&(COLUMN()-1)*5&"
  label COUNT(Col5)''"), ))
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B27:27)=FALSE, 
 QUERY({June2019!$M$3:$Z; July2019!$M$3:$Z; August2019!$M$3:$Z}, 
 "select avg(Col5) 
  where Col1 >  "&(COLUMN()-2)*5&" 
    and Col1 <= "&(COLUMN()-1)*5&"
  label avg(Col5)''"), ))
```